# Is it possible to group up xml documentation from list tag in C#

Tags: c#, doxygen, xml-documentation

I'm using Doxygen for my C# project documentation.
And now I need to make one method's documentation with table.
MSDN documentation is very poor about this tag : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/xmldoc/list

If I use xml `<list type="table">` tag, Doxygen will provide me with nicely looking table.
But I want to make a table with documentation received from more then 1 method.

For example, if I provide methods `MethodA` and `MethodB` with `<list type="table">` tags in xml documentation, Doxygen will generate two tables.
So the question is - is it possible to make him group them by some property(I tried to add `name="my_table" and id="my_table"`, but it didn't work of course).

```
/// <summary>
/// AAA
/// </summary>
/// <list type="table" name="my_table" id="my_table">
///     <item>
///         <term> item AAA term </term>
///         <description> item AAA description </description>
///     </item>
/// </list>
public void MethodA()
{ // Some code here... }

/// <summary>
/// BBB
/// </summary>
/// <list type="table" name="my_table" id="my_table">
///     <item>
///         <term> item BBB term </term>
///         <description> item BBB description </description>
///     </item>
/// </list>
public void MethodB() 
{ // Some code here... }
```

And here's example of how it looks after documentation generation.
[image]

**Update:** Doxygen cannot use  tags for now.
http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/xmlcmds.html

Comment: Yes. Need to see small example of xml with the groups.  I will use Xml Linq from Net Library. (XDocument and XElement).  Looks like you are trying to use XmlDocument and XmlElement.

Comment: @jdweng It's not just a raw xml data. It's C# xml documentation.

Comment: XML is XML.  There is only one type.  Some may be more complex, but you use the same tools to generate and parse.